# Dropdown menu with pop-up option in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use a dropdown menu with AngularJs where I can open a pop up for adding extra item in a Single Page Application.

Is there such a chance in AngularJs ?

How can I achieve this?

(example)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like http://plnkr.co/edit/LYOEntdgLbONNAzH0Ove?p=preview

Define a modal template for each  value - modal1, modal2, ..

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal1.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">modal1 - {{ action }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    modal1
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

and this function

```
$scope.showModal = function(action) {
  if (!$scope.modes.mode) return
  $scope.action = action
  $scope.modal = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: $scope.modes.mode+'.html',
    scope: $scope
  });
}
```

You call showModal from the button `ng-click` handlers (action is just to demonstrate the template / button relationship)

```
$scope.delete = function() {
  $scope.showModal('delete')
}
...
```

Comment: something like that but when you click on exactly to the item in dropdown menu, it will trigger pop up without required to another button. @D.Elvis

Comment: try with adding ng-change="open()" in <select> element